# How to update or write to a file system on Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, overwrite

So I am working with a file systems on Hadoop, and I need to make some update to that file system by using path. In this file system, I have different txt format files. I can get to those files by using path. Below I think i can read a text file on Hadoop by using BufferedReader, but untested yet.

```
fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path), conf);
Path pt = new Path(out + "/" + name  + ".txt");
BufferedReader each_br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
```

I want to write to a particular file by using the path. I couldn't figure that out. Any ideas how?

Thanks,

Comment: First, are you trying to write to HDFS or just a local directory?

Comment: write to HDFS and then copy onto S3.

Comment: see this http://bigdataspeak.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/how-to-write-a-file-in-hdfs-using-hadoop/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have the reading down, and the writing is just as simple.

```
fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path), conf);
FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(new Path("myOutFile"));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
```

That will get you the standard java BufferedWriter.  From that you should be able to do anything you want.

Comment: +1, just remember that `create(Path)` will throw an exception if the file already exists - if you want to overwrite the file, use the `create(Path, true)` method call instead

Comment: @ChrisWhite - even if i use the create(Path,true) its not appending into the file. its overwriting. what should I append?

Comment: @Srivathsa depending on your version of hadoop and the filesystem, appending may not be supported, and if it is, you should be using fs.append - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#append(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)